# How to add some picture to ProgressMonitorInputStreamDialog?

Tags: image, swing, monitor, progress

How to add some picture to ProgressMonitorInputStream dialog? Beside the percentage of loaded data I would like to have some picture above it.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not practical to alter Swing utility classes such as `JOptionPane` or `PrpgressMonitorInputStream`.  By 'practical' I simply mean that in the time it takes you to figure the code, you could have written a replacement that is exactly as required.